# SQL Stored Procedure update loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, t-sql

I am developing "task management system". I am struggling with multi-confirmation of tasks. Mostly my problem is using stored procedure with instead of updating one ID, I want to update multiple id's.

My ID string pulled from website for example looks like = IDs = [12,13,14,15]

I've created stored procedure to cut this array on parts inside of a loop but it doesn't work properly and I have no clue what to do. It takes only first argument and then ends the loop.

Code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ur_tasks_confirm_order]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @user as varchar(50),
    --@id as int,
    @StringToSplit as varchar(max)    
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE 
    @TaskID as int,
    @pos as int,
    @countRecords as int

    While CHARINDEX(',',@StringToSplit)>0
        begin
        select @pos = CHARINDEX(',',@StringToSplit)
        select @TaskID=cast(SUBSTRING(@StringToSplit,1,@pos-1) as int)

            update ur_tasks_details  set StatusOfOrder = 4 Where ID = @TaskID

    return 1;
    end
END
```

I also want to push it inside of "log table" so it would look like this :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ur_tasks_confirm_order]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @user as varchar(50),
    --@id as int,
    @StringToSplit as varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE 
    @TaskID as int,
    @pos as int,
    @countRecords as int

    While CHARINDEX(',',@StringToSplit)>0
        begin
        select @pos = CHARINDEX(',',@StringToSplit)
        select @TaskID=cast(SUBSTRING(@StringToSplit,1,@pos-1) as int)

    update ur_tasks_details  set StatusOfOrder = 4 Where ID = @TaskID

    if @@Rowcount = 1 

        begin 
        DECLARE 
        @OrderNumber as int

            select @OrderNumber = OrderNumber from ur_tasks_details where ID = @TaskID 

            insert into ur_tasks_logs values (@TaskID,@OrderNumber,4,@user,Getdate())
            if @@Rowcount = 1
                Return(0) -- request added succesfully
            ELSE
                Return(5) -- rquest elog not added to log table 

            end
    ELSE

        begin

            Return(4) -- request not added

        end

    end
END
```

Any ideas / tips how to make it work?

Comment: There are hundreds of string splitting functions out there. Although ideally you pass in a table valued parameter and do you splitting in your front end. Either way, once you have split your string you can carry out set-based operations as your normally would in a relational database.

Comment: Otherwise, if you don't want to use a **set based** string splitter (like @DaleK said, there are plenty of them, and SQL Server has had an in-built one since SQL Server 2016) then you could use a table type parameter instead of your `varchar(MAX)` parameter. Either way, a set based solution will *vastly* improve your performance here.

Comment: Hi all, i managed to do this with this line after update :
 select @StringToSplit = SUBSTRING(@StringToSplit,@pos+1,LEN(@StringToSplit)-@pos)

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with the code: the first is that there is an infinite loop in the `WHILE` block, and the second is that if `@StringToSplit` does not contain any commas that you will not process the single item.

The infinite loop happens because `@StringToSplit` never gets updated to remove the portion that was just parsed. To correct this, the `WHILE` loop should be updated and then you should add a section after the loop to handle the last value or the single value. Also, I remove spaces with `LTRIM` and `RTRIM` just to be safe (my experiences as a developer have traumatized me haha). So this fixes the infinite loop and also handles the case when there is a single value without a comma. If you are worried that `@StringToSplit` could contain extra commas and `@TaskID` should never be zero, then I would code against that as well.

```
-- everything before the WHILE loop was fine
WHILE CHARINDEX(',', @StringToSplit) > 0
BEGIN
    SELECT @pos = CHARINDEX(',', @StringToSplit);
    SELECT @TaskID = CAST(SUBSTRING(@StringToSplit, 1, @pos - 1) AS INT);
    IF @TaskID <> 0
    BEGIN
        UPDATE ur_tasks_details SET StatusOfOrder = 4 WHERE ID = @TaskID;
        -- additional logging would go in here
    END;
    -- make sure you remove the portion of @StringToSplit that you just handled!
    SELECT @StringToSplit = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@StringToSplit, @pos + 1, LEN(@StringToSplit))));
END;
-- handle the remaining item that the loop will not catch
SELECT @TaskID = CAST(LTRIM(RTRIM(@StringToSplit)) AS INT);
IF @TaskID <> 0
BEGIN
    UPDATE ur_tasks_details SET StatusOfOrder = 4 WHERE ID = @TaskID;
    -- additional logging would go in here
END;
```

If `@TaskID` is allowed to be zero, then the logic is different - check that the piece we are about to `CAST` has a `LEN` greater than zero, and then do not check that `@TaskID` is not equal to zero. If you did not know, the `LEN` function does a `LTRIM` for you and that is helpful here. So the version where `@TaskID` can be zero looks like this (note the additional variable):

```
DECLARE @CurrentValue VARCHAR(MAX);
WHILE CHARINDEX(',', @StringToSplit) > 0
BEGIN
    SELECT @pos = CHARINDEX(',', @StringToSplit);
    SELECT @CurrentValue = SUBSTRING(@StringToSplit, 1, @pos - 1); 
    IF LEN(@CurrentValue) > 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT @TaskID = CAST(@CurrentValue AS INT);
        UPDATE ur_tasks_details SET StatusOfOrder = 4 WHERE ID = @TaskID;
        -- additional logging would go in here
    END;
    -- make sure you remove the portion of @StringToSplit that you just handled!
    SELECT @StringToSplit = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@StringToSplit, @pos + 1, LEN(@StringToSplit))));
END;
-- handle the remaining item that the loop will not catch
SELECT @CurrentValue = LTRIM(RTRIM(@StringToSplit))
IF LEN(@CurrentValue) > 0
BEGIN
    SELECT @TaskID = CAST(@CurrentValue AS INT);
    UPDATE ur_tasks_details SET StatusOfOrder = 4 WHERE ID = @TaskID;
    -- additional logging would go in here
END;
```

As far as adding it to a log table, I think your logic looks OK for the `INSERT` statement. You will just have to add the logic in the appropriate places - once inside the `WHILE` loop, and then once again after the final `UPDATE` statement.

Hopefully this is clear and helps you!